# Calculation of Pearson's Chi-squared statistic

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am having difficulty in how to calculate the Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic for a contingency table with entries: `(3, 0)` and `(0, 3)` (row-wise).

I was studying Agresti's categorical data analysis and found this table. He calculated it as 6.

Through what calculation did he reach this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the procedure to be followed in order to compute Pearson's Chi-squared statistic.

---

Assume this is your *observed* 2x2 contingency table:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
\hline
 X/Y               & \textrm{cat 1}  & \textrm{cat 2}  & \textrm{tot}      \\
\hline
\textrm{cat 1}  & O_{11}          & O_{12}          & O_{1.}\\
\textrm{cat 2}  & O_{21}          & O_{22}          & O_{2.}\\
\hline
\textrm{tot}    & O_{.1}          & O_{.2}          & O_{..}
\end{array}$$

- there are $O_{11}$ observations that fall within the first category of $X$ $\underline{\textrm{and}}$ within the first category of $Y$;
- There are $0_{2.}$ observations that fall within the second category of $X$;
- the total sample size is $O_{..}$.

**1st step**: Compute the *expected* contingency table

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
E_{11} & E_{12} \\
E_{21} & E_{22}
\end{array}$$

where

$$E_{ij} = \frac{O_{i.} O_{.j}}{O_{..}} \cdot$$

**2nd step** Compute Pearson's statistic:

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{ij} \frac{(O_{ij} - E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}} \cdot$$

Comment: Note that this can be generalised to higher dimensions...

Comment: I'm speculating but if the questioner is entering their data into a stats package rather than calculating the stat from first principles as set out here, it could be that they get an answer different to 6 because the Yates continuity correction might be the default for 2x2 contingency tables.  This is the case, for example in R's chisq-test (which will deliver 2.667 if correct=T, the default; or 6 as per the original question if correct=F)

Comment: @Peter Ellis: Yes, good point!