# Poisson regression comparison of two confusion matrices

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, inference, poisson-regression, confusion-matrix

I have two groups, say $\text{G}$ and $\text{H}$, and they each perform a classification task. Let's say that I get the following confusion matrices

$$\text{G's Performance}\\
\begin{array}
&&\text{A-True} & \text{B-True} & \text{C-True}\\
\text{A-predicted} & 41 & 7 & 13\\
\text{B-predicted} & 3 & 40 &14\\
\text{C-predicted} & 6 & 3 & 13
\end{array}
$$

$$\text{H's Performance}\\
\begin{array}
&&\text{A-True} & \text{B-True} & \text{C-True}\\
\text{A-predicted} & 13 &  6 & 3 \\
\text{B-predicted} & 14 & 41&7 \\
\text{C-predicted} & 13 &  3&40  
\end{array}
$$

My first thought was to do a comparison of accuracy, but both $\text{G}$ and $\text{H}$ have the same accuracy, but while $\text{G}$ struggles to classify category $\text{C}$, $\text{H}$ struggles to classify category $\text{A}$. Testing for unequal accuracy misses this difference.

What I would like to do is hypothesis test that both of my groups, $\text{G}$ and $\text{H}$, are classifying the same way. I do not care how either is performing for this purpose, just if they are classifying differently.

Gung's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148174/247274) seemed pretty promising, and I think adapting it to my task warrants its own post instead of discussing in the comment. Here is my go at the code.

```
library(MASS)
tab <- array(c(41,3,6,7,40,3,13,14,13,13,14,13,6,41,3,3,7,40), dim=c(3,3,2))
tab <- as.table(tab)
names(dimnames(tab)) = c("predicted", "actual", "classifier")
dimnames(tab)[[1]] = c("A", "B", "C")
dimnames(tab)[[2]] = c("A", "B", "C")
dimnames(tab)[[3]] = c("G", "H") 
m1 = loglm(~classifier + actual*predicted, tab)
m2 = loglm(~actual*predicted, tab)
anova(m2, m1)
##########
LR tests for hierarchical log-linear models

Model 1:
 ~actual * predicted 
Model 2:
 ~classifier + actual * predicted 

          Deviance df Delta(Dev) Delta(df) P(> Delta(Dev)
Model 1   49.24281  9                                    
Model 2   49.24281  8    0.00000         1              1
Saturated  0.00000  0   49.24281         8              0
```

Is it the $49.24281 $ and $p\approx 0$ that tells me that $\text{G}$ and $\text{H}$ have significantly different confusion matrices? If so, is this the usual parameter inference that including another variable (classifier) as a predictor results in model much closer in fit to the saturated model? Gung's code left off a response variable. If I want to do this analysis with the usual `glm` function, what is the response variable?

(Next up will be what to do when there are multiple factors with levels (I think I get how to do that with more dimensions to the array) and$-$yikes$-$what to do if there is a continuous covariate, so I want to make sure I understand what is going on with this more basic example.)